# Making New Project Shows Trust Project Message that Doesn't Go Away - Pycharm

Tags: python, file, pycharm, trust

Whenever I make a new project, Pycharm shows this message:
[image]

Clicking "Trust Project" does nothing
[image]

Adding the folder to trusted locations in settings does nothing.
How do i fix this? Its really annoying because it says that with every project.

Answer (score 0):

## Set Trusted location

You can configure what sources PyCharm should consider safe and load such projects automatically during the opening process.

You can add your home directory to the trusted locations to disable PyCharm's warnings about untrusted projects.

#### Configure trusted locations

1. In the **Settings/Preferences** dialog (`Ctrl+Alt+S`), go to **Build, Execution, Deployment | Trusted Locations**.
2. On the **Trusted Locations** settings page, configure the local directories where the projects you consider trusted reside. Click **OK** to save the changes.

[image]
The next time you open a project from one of those locations, PyCharm will automatically load the project.

Comment: I have done this, it doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest you to add your parent folder (which you usually create projects in it) into the `trusted location`